Blending terrain tiles
I have terrain tiles that have normal maps and diffuse maps for their shaders, and separately, subdivison surface modifiers along with separate HeightMaps used in their separate displacement modifiers.
My question is: how can I effectively "blend" such terrain tiles so that they look reasonably smooth?
One thing I tried is applying all modifiers. Then, there is a small bridge-edge-loops option to blend terrain, but at varying distances, this will either distort the diffuse maps too much or make the landscape look too stretched at far distances apart.
So what's the solution here?
